# Further analysis of significant interaction between a covariate and independent variable

Tags: interaction, ancova

I am studying to see if there are differences in mussel feeding ability (CR) based on 10 different food types (Taxa) and water source (Treatment) using the covariates shell length (SL) and Initial food concentration (lin <-I log transformed it).

I made the model:

```
wayancova<-aov(sqrt(CR)~SL+Treatment+lin*Taxa,data=blanks,na.action=na.omit)

             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
SL            1   4.61   4.608   4.286 0.03991 * 
Treatment     1   1.46   1.463   1.360 0.24506   
lin           1   3.05   3.045   2.832 0.09419 . 
Taxa          9  16.37   1.818   1.691 0.09422 . 
lin:Taxa      9  28.61   3.179   2.956 0.00271 **
Residuals   174 187.08   1.075
```

I do not have an interaction between Treatment and the other factors because they were found to not have a significant interaction so I turned it into an additive model.
I had a significant interaction between the covariate Initial concentration and independent variable Taxa (which suggests it is an unequal slopes model).

My advisor now wants me to find which of these interactions are significantly different from each other. I ran a linear regression for each taxa

```
CentricCR<-lm(sqrt(CR)~SL+log(Initial),data=LRcentric)
```

I am now attempting to use this code to compare the `lsmeans` of the interaction, but am very uncertain if this is the right coding.

```
leastsquare<-lsmeans(wayancova,pairwise ~ **Taxa:lin**, adjust = "tukey")
leastsquare$contrasts
cld(leastsquare)
```

I suppose my questions would be, is this the correct approach and methodology to interpreting an ANCOVA, and will my `lsmeans` coding answer which slopes are different?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest comparing the slopes of the estimated trends instead:

```
lstrends(wayancova, pairwise ~ Taxa, var = “lin”)
```

This estimates the slope of the fitted line in `lin` for each level of `Taxa`. Look at the documentation for `lstrends`.

Also, at some point you should switch to the **emmeans** package, because **lsmeans** is soon to be deprecated.